# git post-receive not working correctly

Tags: git, git-post-receive

I have the following problem. I have updated the 'post-receive' to cd into a certain directory and then pull the repo in to deploy it like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /var/www/site
git pull origin master
```

However whenever I do 'git push origin master' on my local machine I get the following:

```
Counting objects: 5, done.
Delta compression using up to 2  threads.
(etc..)
remote: fatal: Not a git repository: '.'
```

Yet when I manually cd to `/var/www/site` and do `git pull origin master` it works brilliantly.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use unset GIT_DIR as following

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /var/www/site || exit
unset GIT_DIR
git pull origin master
exec git-update-server-info
```

You can see more information about **GIT_DIR** here.
[Git Loves the Environment](http://git-scm.com/blog/2010/04/11/environment.html)

Comment: Brilliant, just what I needed. Do you mind explaining why this needs to be done?

Comment: `GIT_DIR` is one of a handful of environment variables that you can set for various git commands.  In a post-receive hook, `$GIT_DIR` is always (?) set to `.`.  If you `cd` elsewhere, `git pull` still sees `$GIT_DIR` set to `.` and expects to find the repo in `.`, but you've moved and it's not there.  Clearing it out makes git go back to its "normal" behavior (looking in `./.git`, in the place you `cd`-ed to).

Comment: Would it not be possible to simply set `GIT_DIR` to the directory being `cd`ed into? It seems redundant to reset `GIT_DIR` and then separately `cd` into the working directory if this is what `GIT_DIR` was designed for. Is there a reason this isn't done?

Answer (score 4):

Another option is you can mention the working directory and git directory in the command.

```
git --work-tree=/home/user/repos/my_app --git-dir=/home/user/repos/my_app/.git <command>
```

e.g:

```
git --work-tree=/home/user/repos/my_app --git-dir=/home/user/repos/my_app/.git status
```