# How can I cd to a folder and run npm start with git hook post-receive?

Tags: node.js, git, npm, githooks

Basically I want to:

```
git --work-tree=/home/aero/server --git-dir=/home/aero/server/.git pull;
ps aux | grep node | grep server-aero-static | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9;
cd /home/aero/server;
npm start;
```

I don't think this would work in post-receive, why? And how can I get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

The Git part should work, provided the remote "origin" is correctly set in `/home/aero/server`, in order for that repo to work properly (as in "[Git `post-receive` not working correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18417707/6309)").

The `npm start` part might be a problem if that command blocks.
In that case (meaning execution in a Git hook), you might consider [using **`pm2`**](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2) to start your application, as explained in "[A Friendly Guide To Automate Deployment For Node.js Apps With Git Hooks](https://medium.com/@aunnnn/automate-digitalocean-deployment-for-node-js-with-git-and-pm2-67a3cfa7a02b)" by [**aunnnn**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6666165/aunnnn).

```
pm2 start npm --name 'my-app' — start \
&& echo "post-receive: app started successfully with pm2".
```

Comment: Yeah I am using pm2 right now (or forever on some other servers) but I like to know if I can do it naked.

Comment: @AeroWang From the article I link, you cannot: not in a hook, where `npm start` would hang/freeze the hook (and the whole Git command)