# git post-receive hook error laravel on git pull command

Tags: laravel, git, shared-hosting

Trying to do git pull a directory with a post-receive script.
Currently all my script does is the following:

```
echo 'Testing post-receive hook'
cd ~/www/test.com/laravel
pwd
git pull
cp -a ~/www/test.com/laravel/public/. ~/www/test.com/public_html/
```

the problem is that when I hit this script it returns remote: fatal: not a git repository: '.' however, if I manually go into ~/www/test.com/laravel and do a git pull it works? any ideas would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer found [git post-receive not working correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9905882/git-post-receive-not-working-correctly)
You have to Unset the git directory with `unset GIT_DIR` before you call git pull